# How can I begin using Wicket?

Tags: eclipse, wicket

I installed Wicket per the rules of the Wicket site. How do I run Wicket within my IDE, Eclipse? I have added all the necessary plug-ins.

Comment: Check out this [Quickstart page](http://wicket.sourceforge.net/wicket-quickstart/eclipse.html).

Comment: this is very old page -- year 2008. There is a newer configuration page available.

Comment: Here's the newer version: http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

Comment: Which part of this constructive and useful question is non-constructive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I expect you have configured as per quick-start guide here: http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html

There is a configuration setting for Eclipse as well. Now, if you have your project in Eclipse and you have [m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) (Maven-2 for Eclipse) installed. Follow the steps below:

1. Right click on the Wicket project folder, select `run As > Maven Clean`, then `run As > Maven Install`. This will build your Wicket project.
2. TO start Jetty, you will need to do some more steps

   - Right click on wicket project folder, 'run As > run configurations..`
   - Create new Maven Build configuration, give a name, select wicket projects directory as `Base Directory`, in `Goals` type in `jetty:run`.  Now, you will have jetty running your application at `localhost:8080/yourAppName`

The Jetty run configuration will be available in `run As` menu for future usage.

This is pretty much it!

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I believe it is the only place which somebody described those essential steps (I took the liberty of fixing the typo of maven goal).