# How to repeatedly run Wicket/Maven/Jetty project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, configuration, jetty, wicket

Thanks to those info http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/wicket/wicket_eclipse_setup/ and [How can I begin using Wicket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119708/how-can-i-begin-using-wicket) now I am able to edit Java code and html files with Eclipse, and run it to get Jetty started.

However there are still two problems which do not allow me to repeatedly run the project:

1. I have to stop previous run in order to run it again
2. unlike regular Java project, where I could simply choose "run", now I have to go into "Run Configuration", select Maven Build type, and below select my project to run, and then finally click "run"

ad.1. How to make Eclipse stop the previous run on next run -- i.e. I would like to just run project, and Eclipse should either run it, or stop previous one and run it again

ad.2. how to "bind" Run/Run to running my configuration (Maven Build / my project)?

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 3):

Another simply option is to use a Start class with a main that runs and embedded jetty. Then you will be able to run and debug your application as a normal desktop java application with your IDE.

Check the example start file that comes with the wicket quickstart here:

https://github.com/jordeu/wicket/blob/master/archetypes/quickstart/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/test/java/Start.java

Comment: +1 from me too, however this is completely another route (btw. it is described in "Wicket in Action"). However I am looking for solving the approach I described -- I guess I miss some trivial steps, after all everything is working but with 2 too many manual steps.